# Adding Multiple Pages At Once In Typo3 Version 9.5

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

In Typo3 version 9.5 the Functions tab seems to be removed. How do I add multiple pages at once without using this Functions tab?

Comment: Please add what you tried so far

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This functionality has been [merged into the backend extension](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/core/Changelog/9.0/Important-81768-CreatePagesAndSortPagesInContextMenu.html) with TYPO3v9.

Just left click on the icon left to your page title in the page tree and select

*More options* > *Create multiple pages*:

[image]